# Weblogic Jersey implementation

Tags: rest, jersey, weblogic

I am trying to deploy a REst based web service onto Weblogic 12C.
While deploying the war, I am getting the following warning and the ping service(or any other service) is not accessible after deployment.

**Warning message:**

```
<Apr 17, 2017 1:03:14 PM EET> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Apr 17, 2017 1:03:14 PM EET> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>
<Apr 17, 2017 1:03:14 PM EET> <Warning> <JAXRSIntegration> <BEA-2192510> <Cannot add Jersey servlet for application class org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig because ApplicationPath annotation is not set on it.>​
```

Below are the other artifacts.

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.test.service.service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**ResourceConfig subclass:**

```
@ApplicationPath("/custom")
public class TestPageService extends ResourceConfig {

    /*Register JAX-RS application components.*/
    public TestPageService () {
    packages("com.test.service.service");
    }

}
```

**Service class:**

```
@Path("/testpageservice")
public class TestServiceImpl{

@Path("/ping")
@GET
public String ping() {
  String responseStr = "This is Test web Service";
}
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Required only when you are using JAX-RS Client -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
   <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>​
```

I have also tried putting prefer-application-packages in weblogic.xml for com.sun.jersey, which did not help.

Please advise how to resolve the problem.

Comment: I found that ping service is available with `/custom/testpageservice/ping` but not with `/rest/testpageservice/ping`

Comment: You are mixing Jersey 1 and Jersey 2. Do you really need a web.xml? Just using the  `@ApplicationPath` enable JAX-RS discovery, without needing of web.xml file.

Comment: Hi thanks Rouliboy, I have removed the servlet mapping from web.xml. But how am I mixing jersey 1 and 2. Can you please point out which one is which version. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `com.sun.jersey` is Jersey 1, `org.glassfish.jersey` is Jersey 2.

Comment: Thanks.. for the clarification.

Comment: Did you solved the "warnings" meaning, where you able to get rid of them? And if so, how?

Comment: Hi Anna,I did not do anything on these Warnings as the service was anyway working.